# How to rotate a two-dimensional array to an arbitrary degree?

Tags: c#, arrays, math

Say I have a bool[][], and I want to rotate it by 37 degrees. I am aware that the transformation wouldn't always be perfect, and that's okay. I've ready plenty of answers on here similar to my question, but the only solutions I've found only solve the problem for 90 degree increments.

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/02/8918130.aspx

Comment: I suspect you're asking an imaging question.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me - how would you rotate a bool? Do you mean you have a matrix of floats?

Comment: @SLaks:  That would be my guess as well, the question being how to rotate a bitmap.  An important piece of information is missing:  rotate around what (point)?

Comment: @hardmath: Also, what should happen to the parts that don't fit, and what should be the filler?

Comment: @SLaks. My question does have to do with imaging. The boolean array represents transparent and non transparent points on an image. When the image is rotated, I would like to know how to efficiently create an array that represents the image and its colors in the rotated state.

Comment: @hardmath The filler can just be transparent space. The parts that don't fit should still be represented, which means a new array for each angle?

Comment: @cory - Do you resize the bitmap to hold a rotated image that might extend outside the bounds of the original bitmap?  Or do you resize the rotated image to fit within the original bounds?

Comment: @mbeckish The parts that don't fit need to still be represented.

Comment: @cory: So, you will need a larger buffer to store it into, which will have to be dimensioned up to sqrt(2) * Width, sqrt(2) * Height. No matter what, except in the orthogonal cases, you'll need a new buffer to write into.

Comment: @cory: You don't understand the size issue.  Draw an example of the image you're trying to create, in the correct size, and you should see what we mean.

Comment: BTW, bool[][] is probably not a good data structure to use for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best way is to loop over the destination locations and for each of them read the correct source location. If you try the other way around (i.e. looping on source and writing on destination) you will end up with gaps.

The rotation formula is simple...

```
source_x = dest_x * c + dest_y * s + x0
source_y = dest_x * -s + dest_y * c + y0
```

where `c` is the cosine of the angle, `s` is the sine of the angle and `x0, y0` are used to correctly translate the rotated image. In psedudocode

```
for y = 0, 1, ... dest_height
    for x = 0, 1, ... dest_width
        src_x = c*x + s*y + x0
        src_y = -s*x + c*y + y0
        copy from source[src_y][src_x] to dest[y][x]
```

`x0, y0` can be computed so that the source center will end up in the destination center by

```
 x0 = src_width/2 - c*dest_width/2 - s*dest_height/2
 y0 = src_height/2 - c*dest_height/2 + s*dest_width/2
```

If instead of just using `c = cos(angle)` and `s = sin(angle)` you scale both of them with a factor `k` the resulting image will be rotated and zoomed around the center.

Note also that the formulas are bilinear in `x` and `y`; this means that you can use the full formula for the complete value for the first pixel of a row and then just do `src_x += c` and `src_y -= s` for each element of the same row because that is what happens when moving from `x` to `x+1`.

Note also that depending on source and destination size it may be that the computed source element is not available because out of the image. In this case there are several normally used options

1. Write a fixed value (e.g. `false`)
2. Don't write that destination cell
3. Do a "clamping" limiting both coordinates to the maximum allowed before reading
4. Do a "tiling" by normalizing coordinates using the modulo operator
5. Do a mirrored continuation by normalizing with TWICE the size and taking the symmetrical value `2*size-value` if normalized value is bigger than the size

Answer (score 4):

Where x, y are your Cartesian coordinates and R is your rotation angle:

```
newx = x * cos(R) - y * sin(R)
newy = x * sin(R) + y * cos(R)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are rotating a bitmap, I'd first look at using an imaging framework (e.g. System.Drawing) to achieve what you want. Say, take your bools, turn it into a 1-bpp bitmap, draw it rotated, and read it back out.

If that's not what you want, you can either use the rotation provided by wberry and apply to each bool, or if performance is at a premium, write your own texturized rectangle rasterizer. To do the latter, look at some old graphics programming textbooks on how to texture map arbitrary 2D polygons.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really, really want to do this yourself, consider using something like [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/) -- more specifically [AForge.Imaging.Filters.RotateBicubic](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/f9841ff5-cd23-b80e-b25d-788b42d14308.htm). This routine handles 24bpp and 8bpp images, so you'd need to rotate the RGB content (as a 24bpp image) separately from the alpha channel (as an 8bpp image).