# Copying triangular image region with PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, affinetransform

I have two PIL images and two sets of corresponding 2D points that make a triangle.

For example:

```
image1:
100x100 pixels
points = [(10,10), (20,20), (10,20)]

image2:
250x250 pixels
points = [(35,30), (75,19), (50,90)]
```

I want to copy the triangular region from image1 and transform it to fit into the corresponding triangular region of image2. Is there any way to do this with PIL without having to copy pixel by pixel and calculate the transformation myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do this with an affine transformation (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114257/transform-a-triangle-to-another-triangle)). After the affine transformation, the destination triangle is drawn to a mask and then pasted on to the destination image. Here's what I came up with:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw
import numpy

def transformblit(src_tri, dst_tri, src_img, dst_img):
    ((x11,x12), (x21,x22), (x31,x32)) = src_tri
    ((y11,y12), (y21,y22), (y31,y32)) = dst_tri

    M = numpy.array([
                     [y11, y12, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [y21, y22, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [y31, y32, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                     [0, 0, 0, y11, y12, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0, y21, y22, 1],
                     [0, 0, 0, y31, y32, 1]
                ])

    y = numpy.array([x11, x21, x31, x12, x22, x32])

    A = numpy.linalg.solve(M, y)

    src_copy = src_img.copy()
    srcdraw = ImageDraw.Draw(src_copy)
    srcdraw.polygon(src_tri)
    src_copy.show()
    transformed = src_img.transform(dst_img.size, Image.AFFINE, A)

    mask = Image.new('1', dst_img.size)
    maskdraw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    maskdraw.polygon(dst_tri, fill=255)

    dstdraw = ImageDraw.Draw(dst_img)
    dstdraw.polygon(dst_tri, fill=(255,255,255))
    dst_img.show()
    dst_img.paste(transformed, mask=mask)
    dst_img.show()


im100 = Image.open('test100.jpg')
im250 = Image.open('test250.jpg')

tri1 = [(10,10), (20,20), (10,20)]
tri2 = [(35,30), (75,19), (50,90)]

transformblit(tri1, tri2, im100, im250)
```

The source 100x100 image looks like this (triangle overlaid in white):

[image: src_before]

The destination 250x250 image looks like this (triangular region filled in with white):

[image: dst_before]

And then after the transformation and pasting, the destination image looks like this:

[image: dst_after]

Comment: Yes, but it didn't seem like there was a way to do that with PIL. It wasn't too much trouble since I got the formula from the referenced post and numpy solves the system of equations for me. What I really wanted to avoid was copying pixel-by-pixel.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

This strategy still involves some pixel manipulation, but can leverage the APIs somewhat.

1. Convert source image into RGBA.
2. Find the smallest enclosing rectangle of your triangle.
3. Manually set all pixels within the rectangle, but NOT part of the triangle, to fully transparent.  (You might be able to do this without too much trouble using sets for the x/y values, `map` and `partial`.)
4. Find the smallest enclosing rectangle of the triangle in the target image.
5. Copy the rectangle into the target image by scaling the source enclosing rectangle to the target size.

Comment: That won't line up the triangle coordinates in image1 with the coordinates in image2

Comment: I still don't think this works. It will only take care of translation and scale, not shear and rotation.

Comment: You didn't mention that in your question.  If by shear you mean offset, then you just have to add the delta x/y when placing over the target.  For rotation, you can calculate the center of the triangle and then apply this rotation formula: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207480/how-to-rotate-a-two-dimensional-array-to-an-arbitrary-degree/6207584#6207584

Comment: I thought that was clear since the triangle are of different size and shape. I ended up using an affine transformation matrix. See my answer for details.